# What is the difference between CrudRepositoryImpl and DefaultCrudRepository in loopback v4?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

There are 2 repository implementation classes in loopback-next repo. The one that is used when a repository is created by CLI is DefaultCrudRepository. We have been using this in many places successfully.
But while looking for ways to customize repository to have dynamic datasource instances, I just saw one CrudRepositoryImpl [here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/4ea98a1b1b054ca256bdb0f452e2951a1e9f3d72/packages/repository/src/repositories/repository.ts#L220). Can someone explain what's the difference ?

Any use case where we will need to use CrudRepositoryImpl ?

Any help will be really appreciated.